# can not pass httpcontextbase into method with HttpContext type variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, moq

I have method expecting HttpContext type variable.

```
public string GetQueryStringValues(HttpContext context)
```

I am writing unit test from article [hanselman article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCSessionAtMix08TDDAndMvcMockHelpers.aspx)  using Moq to create/populate HttpContext and pass into the method as follows:

```
        string url = "http://localhost:51209/WebForm1.aspx?height=6&width=7&length=8&mode=walk";
        HttpContextBase contextbase = MoqHelper.FakeHttpContext(url);
        string result = new Helper(whitelist).GetQueryStringValues(context);
```

I get the following error message:

cannot convert from 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' to 'System.Web.HttpContext'

How do I resolve this with out changing the signature for method GetQueryStringValues ??

Please help.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this without changing signature. However, your signature will be better with abstraction, not concrete type.

Comment: Your method will need to change to take a `HttpContextBase` instead of `HttpContext` - ie: `public string GetQueryStringValues(HttpContextBase context)`

Comment: By abstraction I mean: HttpContextBase - it's an abstract class, HttpContext is a concrete implementation.

Comment: After I am done writing unit test, I have to see if actual asp.net web page will be able to pass in the context object to the method that uses contextbase as input parameter. What do you guys think?

Comment: Abstractions have many benefits - they can be replaced by other implementations, you are able to provide mock implementations (your case), you provide loose coupling, etc. The bottom line is that you will benefit from this change of signature.

Comment: empi, in my asp.net application, I use HttpContext.Current to get context and pass into the method. How do I get instance of HttpContextBase? I am unable to do that

Comment: @dotnet-practitioner - use new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current) - check this link http://splinter.com.au/httpcontext-vs-httpcontextbase-vs-httpcontext